# WPA2 Group Key Renewal -- Will connection be dropped?

Tags: security, wifi

I used to set my WiFi security using WEP to support legacy WiFi dongles that can't handle WPA (or other new encryption scheme).

Recently, I've dumped those old dongles and got new ones. I am now moving to WPA2.

While setting up WPA2, there is a setting called "Group Key  Renewal" that has a default value of 3600 seconds.

Question: Does this mean that all wireless connection to the router will be dropped every 3600 seconds to renew their key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too sure of the technicalities of the key-renewal process, but what I do know is that it should *not* disconnect or drop any wireless connections made to the access point (unless the clients reject the new key or if the signal strength is too weak to negotiate the new key).

Unless there is a specific need to lower the key renewal timer, 3600 should be fine (it is default for most routers) - as long as you have a strong WPA key.

Answer (score -1):

In case the router resets to the default values; this means all the changes are removed including the security settings and the server access password.
I definitelly don't want that for security reasons; so I set the value of Key Renewal Interval to "0".